# How to keep UIButton highlighted until a second touch?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want to keep a button in highlighted state image **until a second touch** to release it to the normal state.

I've try the `dispatch_async` method, but it simply couldn't be back to normal state after another click.

(I'm coding in Swift so `performSelector:WithObject` method doesn't work either.)

Comment: you can use images to set to UIButton and change them on first click and second click.

Comment: You cant hold a highlighted state since  it  automatically gets set/cleared when touch enters/exits during tracking and cleared on up. So you have to use normal and selected state to show your desired image

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I toggle hidden of a label while a button is pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743959/how-do-i-toggle-hidden-of-a-label-while-a-button-is-pressed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will use selected state instead of highlighted. UIButton has already the property so you don't need to create any other property.

```
button.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)

button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton)
{
  sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. You are so helpful. Bravo.

Comment: But if the Button has an Image, then the selected property does not work!!

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is extend the UIButton class, add the "highlited" BOOL flag. After each click just update this flag and set different image.