# What is UIControlEventTouchCancel?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontrolevents

When the user taps and holds down a UIButton in my app, after a while a UIControlEventTouchCancel event is fired.  The Apple documentation for UIControl doesn't have any detailed explanation about this event.  Why is it triggered?  What is it used for?

```
[button addTarget:key action:@selector(keyUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:key action:@selector(keyUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[button addTarget:key action:@selector(keyCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
[button addTarget:key action:@selector(keyDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events), a `UIControlEventTouchCancel` event is due to:

> A system event canceling the current touches for the control.

**Therefore, it's not due to user input that the touch has ended, it's due to a system event (such as a low memory warning, or the app moving into the background).** I have no idea why you are able to trigger it from simply pressing and holding on the button.

I'm pretty sure it's a similar (if not caused by the) event to the `UIResponder`'s [`touchesCancelled:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesCancelled:withEvent:) event. The documentation on this is slightly more detailed:

> This method is invoked when the Cocoa Touch framework receives a system interruption requiring cancellation of the touch event; for this, it generates a UITouch object with a phase of UITouchPhaseCancel. The interruption is something that might cause the application to be no longer active or the view to be removed from the window

Comment: Memory is fine and the app wasn't moved to the background.  I was seeing some anomalies with the button keyDown action and when I added the touch cancel event, it explained the anomaly.  However, I can't figure out what is causing the cancel event to trigger.

Comment: hmm... weird. Are you doing anything in the background that could maybe affect the button, such as animations?

Comment: I figured it out!  My code was removing the button from the view in another method that was refreshing the display.

Comment: ah, makes sense, glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

One scenario is the screen rotation. If you rotate your screen while holding down the button you will get a touch cancel event.