# Send user action to parent uiview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, user-interaction

I am working on user interaction in different uiviews.

I know how to send user interaction on parent view or on it's specific UI components.

In my example, I am sending event to UIButton that is working properly even I tap on outside of UIButton bounds (Please take a look on attached code for more inside).

But I don't know that when I tapping on top view, UIButton TouchDown selector called but TouchUpInside not calling. Why is it happening?

Any suggestions? Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Github code link: https://github.com/jackMac1811/iOSUIInteractionTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All uibutton events carrying their own behavior which enables to execute its bunch of code according to it.

> if you want to invoke both methods tapping on top view you should have to use **touch up outside** instead of **touch up inside event**
>   Here's a very useful link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11390048/4003548

Hope this helps ..

Comment: If you have downloaded my test project from GitHub link. Then you can see that on tap on UIButton, we are getting NSLog for both selectors. TouchUpInside and TouchDown. I know about all UIButton touch methods. I am unable to understand that on tap outside of UIButton, we can get TouchDOwn selector called but TuchUpInside selector will not call.

Comment: A touch-up inside event works where the finger is inside the bounds of the uibutton and touch down event works outside the boundaries _kindly have a look of of that link i have mentioned_.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav... I should read your previous link completely. Thanks for replying.