# Difference between UIControl events

Tags: ios, uislider, uicontrolevents

[Documentation of UIControl Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/):

What is the difference between `UIControlEventTouchDragInside`, `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter`, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`? All seem to be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton events. What's the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389915/uibutton-events-whats-the-difference)

Comment: Already you have the answer you can get it from here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389915/uibutton-events-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 1):

No, those all are not same. Though they are all coming from `UIControl`.

Apple made this things available inside a `struct` for swift and for Objective-C its available inside an `enum`. Both of this are inside `UIControlEvents`. Following are the `struct` & `enum` which you may look.

```
struct UIControlEvents : OptionSetType { //This is for Swift.
    init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
    static var TouchDown: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDownRepeat: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragInside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragOutside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragEnter: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragExit: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchUpInside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchUpOutside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchCancel: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var ValueChanged: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var PrimaryActionTriggered: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var EditingDidBegin: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var EditingChanged: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var EditingDidEnd: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var EditingDidEndOnExit: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var AllTouchEvents: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var AllEditingEvents: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var ApplicationReserved: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var SystemReserved: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var AllEvents: UIControlEvents { get }
}


typedef enum UIControlEvents : NSUInteger { //This is for Objective-C.
   UIControlEventTouchDown               = 1 << 0,
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat         = 1 << 1,
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside         = 1 << 2,
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside        = 1 << 3,
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter          = 1 << 4,
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit           = 1 << 5,
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside           = 1 << 6,
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside          = 1 << 7,
   UIControlEventTouchCancel             = 1 << 8,
   
   UIControlEventValueChanged            = 1 << 12,
   UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered  = 1 << 13,
   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin         = 1 << 16,
   UIControlEventEditingChanged          = 1 << 17,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEnd           = 1 << 18,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit     = 1 << 19,
   
   UIControlEventAllTouchEvents          = 0x00000FFF,
   UIControlEventAllEditingEvents        = 0x000F0000,
   UIControlEventApplicationReserved     = 0x0F000000,
   UIControlEventSystemReserved          = 0xF0000000,
   UIControlEventAllEvents               = 0xFFFFFFFF 
} UIControlEvents;
```

Now coming to the theoretical explanation which apple does for this things separately. BTW I am not explaining all the events but taking your requirements only.

1. `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` - An event where a finger is dragged into the bounds of the control.(I hope you know the difference between `frames` and `bounds`)
2. `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` - An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control.
3. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` - A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

   This are all available from iOS 2.0 onwards. See the difference between `TouchUp` and `TouchDrag` also which will help you to get a clear idea about this things.

Thanks,
Hope this helped.