# Using UIImageView instead of UIButton is not good?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I often `UIImageView` when you tap some actions will be excused instead of `UIButton`. Because if you use `UIButton`, it isn't excused until you release your finger. But if you use `UIImageView`, the action will be excused the moment you touch `UIImageView`. But I'm wondering whether it is good way to make "UIButton" or not because when I use `UIImageView`, I set the tag of `UIImageView`, use `touchesBegan`, and check which `UIImageView` you tap. I'm not sure the way it good or not.

Do you use `UIButton` when you want to do some actions when you touch the object? And what do you think about it?

(I'm sorry I'm a beginner iOS engineer so it might be idiot question.)

Comment: For the `UIButton`, apart from `touchUpInside` there are other gestures too. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can easily be done using `UIButton`, you just need to use different `controlEvents`, for instance like so

```swift
yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourSelector), for: .touchDown)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Because if you use UIButton, it isn't excused until you release your
>   finger.

This is true if you have a function that is triggered at the event `touchUpInside`. If you use the event `touchUpDown`, the function will get triggered right after the user tapped the button. See here all the events: [UIButton events. What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389915/uibutton-events-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

Try it from `.xib` or `.storyboard` file. I think it will help you.

[image]