# Ios Button Actions methods explain each

Tags: ios

Button Actions that are used when create a button Outlet and Action Method called touch up inside by default.and there is more buttons that have differ method can u explain what is this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389915/uibutton-events-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIControlEventTouchCancel**

A system event canceling the current touches for the control.

**UIControlEventTouchDown**

A touch-down event in the control.

**UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat**

A repeated touch-down event in the control; for this event the value of the UITouch tapCount method is greater than one.

**UIControlEventTouchDragEnter**

An event where a finger is dragged into the bounds of the control.

**UIControlEventTouchDragExit**

An event where a finger is dragged from within a control to outside its bounds.

**UIControlEventTouchDragInside**

An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control.

**UIControlEventTouchDragOutside**

An event where a finger is dragged just outside the bounds of the control.

**UIControlEventTouchUpInside**

A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

**UIControlEventTouchUpOutside**

A touch-up event in the control where the finger is outside the bounds of the control.

Comment: You posted a link to a duplicate. Since there is a duplicate there is no reason to also repost the same answer. Please delete this answer.